# Browse MATLAB integrated functions

Tags: matlab

I tried to find the source code for some integrated MATLAB functions. Is there any way to find MATLAB's integrated functions? For example I can't find `hypot` source code.

Comment: Sometimes in the function documentation it will mention the algorithm that is used. But other than that, it would not be possible as most function are compiled mex-code, with matlab wrappers.

Comment: That mean's we can not access most of function's source??

Comment: That is correct the algorithm can be found by searching or if they mention it in the documentation. But the actual implementation pure-source code mostly will not. Which should not surprise you, Matlab is expensive software if you could see the implementation including the toolboxes, you might consider not paying for them and implement them yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most MATLAB functions are supplied as MATLAB source code, and you can view the source by typing `edit <functionname>`. Some of the lower level functions, however, are implemented in C for better performance and are built-in - you can't see the source code. `hypot` is one of these.

However the algorithms are not typically that secret - you can read an [article](http://blogs.mathworks.com/cleve/2012/07/30/pythagorean-addition/) about `hypot` (including the algorithm) on Cleve Moler's blog.